# How to make a primitive type parseable and printable differently?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a new type, which will be `i16`, but print and parse differently:

```
use std::fmt;
use std::str::FromStr;

pub type Data = i16;

impl fmt::Display for Data {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "0x{:04X}", self)
    }
}

impl FromStr for Data {
    type Err = String;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        let hex: String = s.chars().skip(2).collect();
        let d = Data::from_str_radix(&hex, 16)
            .expect(&format!("Can't parse hex '{}' in '{}'", hex, s));
        Ok(d)
    }
}

#[test]
pub fn prints_itself() {
    let data : Data = 42;
    assert_eq!("0x003A", format!("{}", data));
}

#[test]
pub fn parses_itself() {
    let data : Data = 42;
    assert_eq!(data, "0x003A".parse());
}
```

It doesn't compile and I think I understand why. It seems I should declare my type `Data` somehow differently. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work because your `Data` type is just a type **alias**, not a new type. The type is still an `i16`, and you cannot implement traits for types you do not own in your crate by design.

What you probably want is to wrap the `i16` in a struct as:

```
pub struct Data(i16);
```

You will then also need to implement the `UpperHex` trait in order to print hex, and you'll also probably want to implement the `Deref` trait to avoid having to type `Data.0` to access the `i16` every time.

Comment: In the case of implementing the Deref trait, would it look like this? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd1c721036ddac62a9144fca69b8f9ea

Comment: Yup you got it. Though I think a clearer example of why you might want to do this might look more like: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4da7006a106c8d26b5c0c35b07e3e25e
Our function `add` takes references to `i16`s but we are able to pass in references to our `Data` struct thanks to deref coercion.

Comment: I have no idea how I didn't find this earlier, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

`type Foo = Bar` doesn't create a new type, it is a "type alias". You can think of it as if the compiler goes and checks for locations of `Foo`, and replaces them with `Bar` wherever it is used.

Instead, you want a new type: `struct Foo(Bar)` and implement any functions/traits you need on the new type.

This is a pretty common pattern, and I have written a library that takes some of the boilerplate out of it, though it is totally optional: https://crates.io/crates/microtype